Is there an easy way to add PostCSS to a SASS React project?
I have a React project that uses SASS with the following configurations:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.70.0"
  }
}

I would like to add PostCSS to remove repetitive/duplicate CSS Rules and optimize the styling files.
Admittedly, I do not know much about PostCSS.
I tried adding the following as my postcss.config.js:
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('cssnano')({
      preset: 'default',
    }),
  ],
};

and the following command:
npm install --save-dev postcss postcss-cli postcss-import autoprefixer cssnano postcss-loader

However, I do not believe anything happened and duplicate css lines were still there when inspecting in the browser.
Here is a link to my project: qamous.org

Your project was created using the (deprectated) CRA, which means your code is handled by webpack via react-script config. This config already has a loader configured with PostCSS, as you can see here:
{
  // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
  // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
  // package.json
  loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
  options: {
    postcssOptions: {
      // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
      ident: 'postcss',
      config: false,
      plugins: !useTailwind
        ? [
          'postcss-flexbugs-fixes',
          [
            'postcss-preset-env',
            {
              autoprefixer: {
                flexbox: 'no-2009',
              },
              stage: 3,
            },
          ],
          // Adds PostCSS Normalize as the reset css with default options,
          // so that it honors browserslist config in package.json
          // which in turn let's users customize the target behavior as per their needs.
          'postcss-normalize',
        ]
      : [
          'tailwindcss',
          'postcss-flexbugs-fixes',
          [
            'postcss-preset-env',
            {
              autoprefixer: {
              flexbox: 'no-2009',
            },
            stage: 3,
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
    sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment,
  },
},

If you don't intend to get out of CRA and wish to update this config, you can either eject your app, or use a tool such as craco or react-app-rewired to override the config.

how would I go about transitioning off of CRA into what is considered standard practice

@CairoMisr I think you can just search for "migrating from CRA to Vite"

Is Vite the same syntax as react? Would I need to change any content?

@CairoMisr Vite has no relation to React, it's a build tool. You can read about what it does and how to use it on its docs.
